Blender 4.2, Python 3.12.4 - Python script import Blender
I inherited a Python script which, I suppose, was working (with previous? versions of Blender and Python). Now I got following message:
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Blender'

Parts of script which may be helpful to find out the reason of above. INSTRUCTIONS indicate that script should be loaded and executed inside Blender:
#!BPY

...

# INSTRUCTIONS (You definitely want to read this!): 
#      Once the script is loaded in Blender, hit alt-p. This will bring up
#      the main interface panel...

...

import math
import Blender
from Blender import *
from Blender import NMesh
from Blender.Draw import *
from Blender.BGL import *
from Blender import Material
from Blender import Window

...


After installing Blender 4.2 the Blender.py script location is (in case it is important):
C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.2\4.2\scripts\presets\keyconfig

Tried to find answers on web but with no success. I hope for explanation of that crash and tips on how to deal with it.

@Allan Wind I think it would be hard to verify it. But this script (I guess) converts .blend files to .msh files, and we have such files which were converted some years ago. Import works fine in standard way - I mean when you import one python script into another one. I work on Windows.

It's the difference between porting a script or fixing the environment vs  open ended debug and/or development effort.  You may not care of course.  In any case I suggest you update the question with possible paths to those imports (otherwise that is the task at hand) and if they are there then maybe it's search path thing?

https://docs.blender.org/api/4.2/search.html?q=NMesh&check_keywords=yes&area=default doesn't turn anything up. BGL is depcreated.  The docs talk about import bpy and external search doesn't mention "import Blender" anywhere.  The Blender.py file you found, I think, is unrelated to what you need.  It does mention that module in 2.48 for instance.

Thanks for your efforts. I guess this works on some ancient Blender versions. So it seems like all I can do is to make a virtual machine and test some old configurations.
